# select query with PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I ran this PL/SQL script, I want to store this PL/SQL in a procedure so that I would give it one parameter and returns info about that parameter, for now I ran it separately outside the procedure but I get the following error, please your help :

> error signaled in parallel query server

```
declare
a VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
b VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);
c VARCHAR2(50 CHAR);
d VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);
e VARCHAR2(100);
f VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);

BEGIN
    SELECT
      col1 ,
      col2,
      col3,
      col4,
      col5,
      col6,
    INTO
      a,
      b,
      c,
      d,
      e,
      f
   FROM
     MY_TABLE
   WHERE
     col1= 123;
  dbms_output.put_line(a||','||b||','||c||','||d||','||e||','||f);
END;
```

Comment: I think the comma after col6 is wrong in this code. Still, that error is weird.

Comment: Please show the whole error stack you get, and the table definition and sample data. You're treating `col1` as both a number and a string, so which is it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a misplaced comma (,) after col6. Remove it the code will work:

```
declare
a VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
b VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);
c VARCHAR2(50 CHAR);
d VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);
e VARCHAR2(100);
f VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);

BEGIN
    SELECT
      col1 ,
      col2,
      col3,
      col4,
      col5,
      col6,
    INTO
      a,
      b,
      c,
      d,
      e,
      f
   FROM
     MY_TABLE
   WHERE
     col1= 123;
  dbms_output.put_line(a||','||b||','||c||','||d||','||e||','||f);
END;
```

If you want to create a procedure then here goes the code:

```
declare
a VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
b VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);
c VARCHAR2(50 CHAR);
d VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);
e VARCHAR2(100);
f VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);

BEGIN
    SELECT
      col1 ,
      col2,
      col3,
      col4,
      col5,
      col6
    INTO
      a,
      b,
      c,
      d,
      e,
      f
   FROM
     MY_TABLE
   WHERE
     col1= 123;
  dbms_output.put_line(a||','||b||','||c||','||d||','||e||','||f);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I really was stuck on this, but this is my final answer as the query returns more than one row, and it works just fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_fun
(
  PARAM1 IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
    ref_curs SYS_REFCURSOR;
    a VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
    b VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);
    c VARCHAR2(50 CHAR);
    d VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);
    e VARCHAR2(100);
    f VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);
BEGIN
    OPEN ref_curs FOR 
      SELECT
       col1 ,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4,
       col5,
       col6
     FROM 
      my_table
     WHERE 
       col1= = PARAM1 ;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col1 ,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6');
     LOOP
        FETCH ref_curs INTO a,b,c,d,e,f;
        EXIT WHEN ref_curs%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a||','|| b||','||c||','||d||','||e||','||f);
    END LOOP;
   CLOSE ref_curs;
END my_fun;
```